# Compare password with last three months passwords

Tags: sql, asp.net-ajax, c#-2.0

I'm working on an application in ASP.NET 2.0, and i have given a task that passwords should not match with last three months c#.net.
For first three months passwords fields will b null i will store them in first three months but from 4th month what i have to do how will i store password in first field again after comparing password with all fields.Tell me some solutions my mind is totally stucked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the best way to do this is to have a separate table consisting of the userID, password hash and timestamp. You would insert into here when a password is changed, timestamp would be of the current time on insert.

```
CREATE TABLE `oldpasswords` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`,`password`, `timestamp`)
);
```

Then you can query this table when the user tries to change their password:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM oldpasswords where userid = :p_userid and 
    password = :p_pass and timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

if the count > 0, they've used it within the last 3 months. If not, insert it into this table and change the main user table record as well.

You would probably also want to clean up this table periodically.

```
DELETE FROM oldpasswords WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

would delete anything older than 3 months, since we don't really need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking at a table that stores "retired" passwords, associated with which user account it belonged to and when it was changed. When they go to change the work flow goes:

- Check if new password is same as current password
- Check if new password is in "old password" database (associated with that user) and falls within the time range

If both of those are **false**, move on to the change:

- Add the current password as a new entry to the "old password" database (with timestamp)
- Change the user's password to the new one and save it back to their profile
- (Optional) Prune the "old password" database for entries older than we care about.

At least that's how I would tackle it.